# The best overload match for "..." has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bing-maps, isolatedstorage

I am writing a program that needs to save some coordinates (latitude and longitude values).
Writing these values doesn't seem to be a problem, just when I load them, and apply a map pushpin to the loaded coordinates.  Heres my code I'm using to load:

```
        try
        {
            //Read the file from the specified location.
            fileReader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("cords.txt", FileMode.Open, fileStorage));
            //Read the contents of the file (the only line we created).
            string cords = fileReader.ReadToEnd();


            Pushpin car = new Pushpin();
            car.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            car.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            car.Content = "You Parked Here";
            car.Tag = "carPushpin";
            car.Location = cords;  //getting error here...
            this.map.Children.Add(car);
            this.map.SetView(cords, 18.0);  // ...and here

            //Write the contents of the file to the TextBlock on the page.
            fileReader.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Debug Errror-no cords.txt");
        }
```

and the error I'm getting:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to
>   'System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate'
>
> The best overloaded method match for
>   'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Core.MapBase.SetView(System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate,
>   double)' has some invalid arguments

and

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to
>   'System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate'

Hope you guys can help me out

---

I have edited my code to the best of my ability, but still cannot fix the issue...
The edited code:

```
        try
        {
            //Read the file from the specified location.
            fileReader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("latitude.txt", FileMode.Open, fileStorage));
            //Read the contents of the file (the only line we created).
            string carlatitude = fileReader.ReadToEnd();

            fileReader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("longitude.txt", FileMode.Open, fileStorage));
            //Read the contents of the file (the only line we created).
            string carlongitude = fileReader.ReadToEnd();
            fileReader.Close();

            carlocation = new GeoCoordinate(carlatitude, carlongitude);

            Pushpin car = new Pushpin();
            car.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            car.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            car.Content = "You Parked Here";
            car.Tag = "carPushpin";
            car.Location = carlocation;
            this.map.Children.Add(car);
            this.map.SetView(watcher.Position.Location, 18.0);

        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Debug Errror-no cords.txt");
        }
```

Comment: which line is giving error?

Comment: Error is obvious, you're passing string but it requires `GeoCoordinate` Type

Comment: I think the most important thing is to understand why you are getting that error, and learn how to troubleshoot it next time.

Comment: Do you just need to change this.map.SetView(watcher.Position.Location, 18.0) to this.map.SetView(carlocation, 18.0)? From your code snippet, we have no idea what watcher.Position.Location is.

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert your string representation of `coords` into a `System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate` and pass that to the SetView method.